# Linear Regression on smoothed timeseries in R

Tags: r, time-series, smoothing

I perform a regression with two timeseries objects. It works like that (dummy values):

```
ts1 <- ts(1:10,start=0,frequency=1)
ts2 <- ts(1:10,start=0,frequency=1)
class(ts1) # "ts"
lagmat = "ts1 ~ ts2"
armod <- dyn$lm(as.formula(lagmat))
```

The problem arises when the timeseries are smoothed before the regression:

```
ts1 <- ts(1:10,start=0,frequency=1)
ts2 <- ts(1:10,start=0,frequency=1)
ts1 <- smooth(ts1)
ts2 <- smooth(ts2)
class(ts1) # "tukeysmooth" "ts"  
lagmat = "ts1 ~ ts2"
armod <- dyn$lm(as.formula(lagmat))
```

Error in zooreg(coredata(x), start = xtsp[1], end = xtsp[2], frequency = frequency) : 
  “data” : attempt to define invalid zoo object

My idea was to extract the timeseries object somehow. With tho following lines before the regression it works:

```
ts1 <- ts(as.vector(ts1),start=start(ts1), frequency=frequency(ts1))
ts2 <- ts(as.vector(ts2),start=start(ts2), frequency=frequency(ts2))
```

Why does the first version not work and is there a better way to do it than creating new timeseries?

Comment: Get rid of `as.formula`.  It should be `dyn$lm(lagmat, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something in the dym package. This seems to work just fine:

```
lm(ts1s ~ ts2s)
```

of if you prefer to use the Arm package:

```
library(arm)
fit.1 = lm(ts1s ~ ts2s) 
display(fit.1)
```